# Adding attribute value to core data IF value already exists

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have to say that everyone on the forum has been really helpful with my attempts at learning core data.

I am adding attribute values to my core data entities and creating a relationship when the user selects a row as shown below:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{

UIAlertView *messageAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                 initWithTitle:@"Row Selected" message:@"Added to Routine!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    // Create a new device
    ExcerciseInfo *info = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSManagedObject *routineEntity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Routines"inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSManagedObject *routineEntityDetail = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"RoutinesDetails" inManagedObjectContext:context];

[routineEntityDetail setValue:routineEntity forKey:@"routineinfo"];

    [routineEntity setValue: RoutineText  forKey:@"routinename"];
    [routineEntityDetail setValue: info.details.muscle  forKey:@"image"];
```

How would I include an `IF statement` whereby if the `routinename` already exists the new entry would be added to the existing relationship?

Is this easily possible from the current code? So the Test Routines will be grouped instead of showing separately and the detail view would include both entries. Would `NSPredicate`be appropriate here? Or perhaps the use of `distinctUnionOfObjects`?

You thoughts and comments will be appreciated.

[image][image]

**AS REQUESTED -**

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"Routines" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
    initWithKey:@"routinename" ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                        managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                   cacheName: nil];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;
```

Comment: Can you share your `ManagedObjectModel`? Is `RoutineDetails` in a one-to-many relationship with `RoutineEntity`?

Comment: @MarkoNikolovski I have updated the question. Yes the entities are in a 1-to-many relationship. I have included a snap shot of the entities.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to care about this, you can simply insert a new `RoutineDetails` object and Core Data takes care of the rest. When you auto-generate the `NSManagedObject`subclasses of your DB tables, Core Data automatically generates accessor methods for all relationships, where you can add and remove single or multiple instances of `RoutineDetails` from `Routines`.

To create `NSManagedObject` subclasses, go to your `ManagedObjectModel` click on `Editor->Create NSManagedObject subclass…` and create subclasses for your entities:

[image: Create subclasses]

In your new subclass, you'll see methods like:

```
@interface Routines (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)
- (void)addRoutineDetailsObject:(RoutineDetails *)value;
- (void)removeRoutineDetailsObject:(RoutineDetails *)value;
- (void)addRoutineDetails:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeRoutineDetails:(NSSet *)values;
```

Than you can access all the `RoutineDetails` directly through the `Routines` object (you'll get an `NSSet` of `RoutineDetails`), and furthermore you can add new objects with

```
[routineEntity addRoutineDetailsObject:routineEntityDetail];
```

not caring if an object already exists or not. Core Data will do the right thing.

Comment regarding Core Data: Core Data can have a lot boilerplate code for simple things like fetching. Take a look at the [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/tree/master) project, which is much less verbose and does wonders.

**EDIT:** Whenever you previously created `NSManagedObject`, now you can directly use your own classes, i.e. `Routines`. That way you'll have access to all the "new functionality".

Comment: Hi Marko, thanks for the great answer. The only issue i'm getting now is it is saying `No visible @interface for 'NSManagedObject' declares the selector addRoutinedetObject`. I have never worked with subclasses before.

Comment: Did you create the `NSManagedObject` classes? Also, don't forget to include them in the `.m` file.

Comment: Ah, and also when you create objects instead of: `NSManagedObject *routineEntity` use `Routines *routineEntity`

Comment: Hi Marko, yeah I created the classes when I made the entities. Thanks for the help. It still creates individual entries every time the row is click and doesn't group them. The detail view still works but I presume the way you suggested is more efficient than the way I previously did it. I'm not sure if the way I am adding the routines is flawed as the excercises are added when u click a row and the routine name is stored in a string and added too. You have cleared up my understanding of subclasses though!

Comment: Hi Marko, I have decided to accept your answer as you have cleared up a few issues for me and worked hard to help me. thank you.

Comment: Thanks! Do you want to group `RoutineDetails` by which `Routine` they are in?

Comment: Yeah, I am looking to group all `RoutineDetails` by which `Routine` they are in. So all RoutineDetails with a relationship to the same Routine will be grouped.  Like `Routine` called **Test** with `RoutineDetails` **Crunch** and **Chest Press** will be grouped in the detailview

Comment: And this detail view is a big table view with all the `RoutineDetails`?

Comment: yeah the detail view contains the associated RoutineDetails displayed in a UITableView

Comment: Well, given an array of `Routine` objects, the `numberOfSections:` would be the `routineArray.count`; the `numberOfRowsInSection:` would be the `routineArray[section].details.count` (`details` is the `NSSet` of `RoutineDetails` corresponding to a `Routine`) and than you can wire up everything as needed in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.